# Why does uWSGI fail to start in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi, supervisord

I am relatively new to using uWSGI to serve Python applications and I am attempting to start a uWSGI process in emperor mode with a vassal, but every time I try to start uWSGI inside of Docker with the following command (as `root`):

```
# /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
```

What I get as a response is:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
2.0.13.1
```

The `emperor.ini` configuration file looks like:

```
# files/etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
die-on-term = true
log-date = true
```

While the only vassal's configuration looks like:

```
# files/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/application.ini
[uwsgi]
app_dir = /var/www/server
plugin = python
master = true
callable = app
chdir = %(app_dir)
mount = /=%(app_dir)/start.py
protocol = uwsgi
socket = :8079
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

buffer-size = 32768
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
processes = 1

stats = 127.0.0.1:1717
```

(**NB:** The filenames above are given in terms of where they live relative to the Dockerfile which will then copy them to the correct locations, basically removing the prefix `files`)

Currently the uWSGI Docker image I'm using is built off of an `ubuntu:trusty` base image (though I've tried `ubuntu:latest` and `alpine:latest` and encountered the same problem), and although I am attempting to launch the uWSGI process with supervisor, as stated previously, it also fails when run directly from the command line. In the Docker image I'm installing uWSGI using `pip` but have also tried using `apt-get` with the same result.

I should also mention that I've tried different versions of uWSGI 2.0.13.1 and 1.9.something with the same result, if that helps.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Sean Quinn "me@mail.com"

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
      ack-grep git nano \
      supervisor \
      build-essential gcc python python-dev python-pip

RUN sed -i 's/^\(\[supervisord\]\)$/\1\nnodaemon=true/' /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf \
 && sed -i 's/^\(\[supervisord\]\)$/\1\nloglevel=debug/' /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf \
 && sed -i 's/^\(files = .*\)$/;\1/' /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf \
 && sed -i 's/^\(\[include\]\)$/\1\nfiles = \/etc\/supervisor\/conf.d\/*.conf/' /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

ENV UWSGI_VERSION 2.0.13.1

RUN pip install uwsgi==${UWSGI_VERSION}

RUN mkdir -p /etc/uwsgi \
 && mkdir -p /etc/uwsgi/apps-available \
 && mkdir -p /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled \
 && mkdir -p /var/log/uwsgi

COPY files/etc/supervisor/conf.d/uwsgi.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/uwsgi.conf
COPY files/etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini

VOLUME /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
VOLUME /var/www

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
CMD ["-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

As mentioned, the `supervisord` process attempts to launch the uWSGI process using the following supervisor configuration.

```
# files/etc/supervisor/conf.d/uwsgi.conf
[program:uwsgi]
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
user=root
```

The application Python files are mounted in a subdirectory of `/var/www` and the application uWSGI configuration is mounted into `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled`.

The bizarre thing is, if I install supervisor and uWSGI on a new Ubuntu VM (outside of Docker) with all of the configuration and files in place I can see uWSGI properly process the `emperor.ini` and read the vassal `.ini` files. I haven't yet attempted to add nginx into the equation because I want to make sure uWSGI is starting and reading configuration files correctly first and foremost.

Is there any way to increase the logging or ascertain why I'm only seeing what appears to be the version number of the uWSGI binary? It's like the uWSGI process is completely ignoring command line options. I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can give!

Comment: How do you start uwsgi and do you get any errors? Try adding logto = /path/to/project/error.log to your uwsgi config for logging.

Comment: @MohammadAmin I have tried starting uwsgi both through supervisor and directly as root with the command `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini` (see above), I can try adding the `logto` option but my understanding is that without it, uwsgi should log directly to the console. Assuming that is accurate, what I mention above is what I see: no errors, the only output is the version number. Thanks!

Comment: I remember having the same issue, but I think my problem went away by starting it through supervisor.

Comment: To complement @Sean Quinn's own answer, [here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/898)'s a Github issue related to this problem, where the makers of uWSGI say it's expected behavior, because it is basically like configuring uWSGI through environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **tl;dr** don't use `UWSGI_VERSION` as an environment variable, apparently it forces uWSGI to only print the version number instead of start?

I believe I solved my own issue!

After experimenting with other uWSGI images on Docker's hub, I found that they were also running into the same issue so I began to look further into possible configuration issues. I tried changing permissions among other things.

I noticed however that when I used [jpetazzo/nsenter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) to enter the running container that I saw uWSGI start (rather than simply output the uWSGI version information as highlighted above). When entering using `docker exec`, uWSGI would only print the version information. After playing around a bit more, I discovered that issuing the command `su -` from within the container launched using `docker exec` I again saw uWSGI start.

After some inspection, I discovered several differences in the environment variables between the `root` user in one shell vs. another. It led me to the `UWSGI_VERSION` environment variable, which appears to have been the culprit because removing `UWSGI_VERSION` allowed uWSGI to start.

I modified my Dockerfile to use `UWSGI_PIP_VERSION` instead as the environment variable to indicate the version of uWSGI to install, which seems to be a safe alternative to `UWSGI_VERSION`. YMMV.

Comment: I just struggled for 3 hours with this exact problem and also figured out for myself that the UWSGI_VERSION environment variable in my Dockerfile was the culprit. Thanks for confirming this, though!